# Rails 4 and memcache. Can I clear the cache for particular namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, memcached

I am using Rails 4, with several namespaces all caching to a single memcached instance. Is there a way for me to clear all the cached keys for a particular namespace without affecting the other namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this only in Rails console, but it seems you can use `Rails.cache#delete_matched` to flush a particular namespace.

When you write a value and pass a namespace key, that namespace key just gets prepended to the value's key. You can see this by doing something like:

```
cache.write(:foo_key, 'bar_value', namespace: 'baz_namespace')
cache.fetch(:'baz_namespace:foo_key') #=> 'bar_value'
```

So you can use `#delete_matched` to clear all values within a namespace like so:

```
Rails.cache.delete_matched(/baz_namespace:/)
```

**UPDATE**:

Unfortunately `delete_matched` is not supported by memcached. :-/